# JSON Alamofire POST request error - Value of tuple type

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am not able to understand the error in `Alamofire` can anyone explain the issue.

> Value of tuple type '(NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?,
>   Result)' (aka '(Optional,
>   Optional, Result)') has no member
>   'result'

[image: screenshot]

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UITableViewController {


var dataArray = Array<JSON>()
//var dataArray :NSMutableArray=[]
//

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://104.131.162.14:3033/api/ios/detail").validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                //print("JSON: \(json)")

                var trafficJson = json["traffic_partners"]
                trafficJson["type"] = "Traffic"
                self.dataArray.append(trafficJson)

                var newsJson = json["news"]
                newsJson["type"] = "News"
                self.dataArray.append(newsJson)


                var categoryJson = json["category"]
                categoryJson["type"] = "Category"
                self.dataArray.append(categoryJson)


                var topFreeApps = json["top_free_apps"]
                topFreeApps["type"] = "TopApps"
                self.dataArray.append(topFreeApps)


                var topSites = json["top_sites"]
                topSites["type"] = "TopSites"
                self.dataArray.append(topSites)


                var trendingVideos = json["tranding_video"]
                trendingVideos["type"] = "TrendingVideos"
                self.dataArray.append(trendingVideos)


                var sports = json["sports"]
                sports["type"] = "Sports"
                self.dataArray.append(sports)


                var jokes = json["jokes"]
                jokes["type"] = "Jokes"
                self.dataArray.append(jokes)

                //print(self.dataArray[0]["detail"][0].object)
                //print(self.dataArray[2]["detail"].object)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }

    //tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (dataArray[indexPath.row]["type"].string == "Traffic") {
        return 185
    }
    else if (dataArray[indexPath.row]["type"].string == "News") {
        return 290
    }
    else if (dataArray[indexPath.row]["type"].string == "Category") {
        return 100.0
    }
    else if (dataArray[indexPath.row]["type"].string == "TopApps") {
        return 180
    }
    else if (dataArray[indexPath.row]["type"].string == "TopSites") {
        return 240
    }
    else if (dataArray[indexPath.row]["type"].string == "TrendingVideos") {
        return 290
    }
    else if (dataArray[indexPath.row]["type"].string == "Sports") {
        return 290
    }
    else if (dataArray[indexPath.row]["type"].string == "Jokes") {
        return 320.0
    }
    else {
        return 600
    }
    //return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArray.count
}
```

Comment: if u use swift 3 u must use Alamofire version 4.0 and bigger

Comment: What version of Swift and Alamofire are you using?

Comment: Alamofire at "2.0.2"
Swift 2

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
switch response.result {
case .Success(let JSON):
    print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
```

Comment: And in Alamofire 4, that's `case .success(let value): print(value)`.